# Why do I sometimes need key() in lists?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

I have a component with some mutable state list. I pass an item of that, and a callback to delete the item, to another component.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyApp() {
  val myItems = mutableStateListOf("1", "2", "3")
  LazyColumn {
    items(myItems) { item ->
      MyComponent(item) { toDel -> myItems.remove(toDel) }
    }
  }
}
```

The component calls the `delete` callback in a `clickable` Modifier.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyComponent(item: String, delete: (String) -> Unit = {}) {
  Column {
    Box(
      Modifier
        .size(200.dp)
        .background(MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
        .clickable { delete(item) }
    ) {
      Text(item, fontSize = 40.sp)
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine. But when I change the `clickable` for my own Modifier with `pointerInput()` then there's a problem.

```
fun Modifier.myClickable(delete: () -> Unit) =
  pointerInput(Unit) {
    awaitPointerEventScope { awaitFirstDown() }
    delete()
  }

@Composable
fun MyComponent(item: String, delete: (String) -> Unit = {}) {
  Column {
    Box(
      Modifier
        .size(200.dp)
        .background(MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
        .myClickable { delete(item) } // NEW
    ) {
      Text(item, fontSize = 40.sp)
    }
  }
}
```

If I click on the first item, it removes it. Next, if I click on the newest top item, the old callback for the now deleted first item is called, despite the fact that the old component has been deleted.

I have no idea why this happens. But I can fix it. I use `key()`:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyApp() {
  val myItems = mutableStateListOf("1", "2", "3")
  LazyColumn {
    items(myItems) { item ->
      key(item) { // NEW
        MyComponent(item) { toDel -> myItems.remove(toDel) }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So why do I need `key()` when I use my own modifier? This is also the case in this code from [jetpack](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/blob/e071acff9947527e38364ee07699e1b3a5aa3488/AnimationCodelab/finished/src/main/java/com/example/android/codelab/animation/ui/home/Home.kt#L258), and I don't know why.

---

As the accepted answer says, Compose won't recalculate my custom Modifier because `pointerEvent()` doesn't have a unique key.

```kotlin
fun Modifier.myClickable(key:Any? = null, delete: () -> Unit) =
  pointerInput(key) {
    awaitPointerEventScope { awaitFirstDown() }
    delete()
  }
```

and

```kotlin
    Box(
      Modifier
        .size(200.dp)
        .background(MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
        .myClickable(key = item) { delete(item) } // NEW
    ) {
      Text(item, fontSize = 40.sp)
    }
```

fixes it and I don't need to use `key()` in the outer component. I'm still unsure why I don't need to send a unique key to `clickable {}`, however.

Comment: Check https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#item-keys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compose is trying to cache as many work as it can by localizing scopes with keys: when they haven't changes since last run - we're using cached value, otherwise we need to recalculate it.

By setting `key` for lazy item you're defining a scope for all `remember` calculations inside, and many of system functions are implemented using `remember` so it changes much. Item index is the default key in lazy item

So after you're removing first `item`, first lazy item gets reused with same context as before

And now we're coming to your `myClickable`. You're passing `Unit` as a `key` into `pointerInput`(It has a `remember` inside too). By doing this you're saying to recomposer: never recalculate this value until context changes. And the context of first lazy item hasn't changed, e.g. `key` is still same index, that's why lambda with removed `item` remains cached inside that function

When you're specifying lazy item `key` equal to `item`, you're changing context of all lazy items too and so `pointerInput` gets recalculated. If you pass your `item` instead of `Unit` you'll have the same effect

So you need to use `key` when you need to make use your calculations are not gonna be cached between lazy items in a bad way

Check out more about lazy column keys in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#item-keys)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, sending a unique key to `pointerEvent()` fixes it without using a `key()` in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Jetpack compose optimizes the re-compose by only recomposing Widget which value has been changed.

In your Custom implementation of `Modifier.myClickable` when item list is changing due to deletion, only the inner `Text(item, fontSize = 40.sp)` will be recomposed since item has changed and it is the only one which is reading `item`. The outer  `Box()` is not recomposed, hence it is holding the previous callback. But When you add `key(item)`, the outer box will also be re-composed as the key value has changed. Hence it is working after adding the key.

So why is was working with `Modifier.clickable { delete(item) }`?

I think Compose kept track of change in the callback `clickable { delete(item) }`. So when the callback changed due to item deletion, it recomposed `MyComponent`, Hence is was working with `clickable`

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful description of how it calculates changes. I knew the concept before but your explanation really helped me grok it. I'm not sure why `clickable` works but, as the accepted answer says, I can send a key to `pointerInput()` a unique key and it works without using `key()` in the outer component.