# LazyVerticalGrid after delete item, the view is recomposed, but deleted item remain as 'ghost'

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to using jetpack compose and I have this problem. I have a LazyVerticalGrid which is populated from a list taken from a firestore database, when I delete an item through the application, the view is updated and the deleted item is not displayed, but if I click another item which is at the location of the deleted item, in the logs I see the references to the deleted item and if I click on the next item, I see that the previous one is selected. It is as if the 'ghost' of the deleted element remains and the indices are distorted.

In the **BrandViewModel** I have:

```
   val brands = storageService.brands
```

in **StorageService**:

```
   val brands: Flow<List<Brand>>
```

In **StorageServiceImpl**:

```
override val brands: Flow<List<Brand>>
        get() =auth.currentUser.flatMapLatest { user ->
            currentBrandCollection(user.id).snapshots().map { snapshot -> snapshot.toObjects() }
        }
```

In the **Brand Screen**:

```
 val brands by viewModel.brands.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(initialValue = emptyList())
 ..........

 LazyVerticalGrid(
            state = listGridState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(vertical = 4.dp)
                .padding(horizontal = 4.dp)
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)
                .padding(contentPadding),
            columns = GridCells.Adaptive(minSize = 124.dp),
        ) {
            itemsIndexed(brands) { index, brandItem->
         ..........
```

[initial list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItXKC.jpg)

[Select item card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0erWR.jpg)

[Delete item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFGje.png)

[On tap on General Card, is select previous Card, Ferrarelle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8dEy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem, solved by providing to pointerInput inside items() {} the same key as for element of LazyVerticalGrid

More detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68794149/19258573

```
LazyVerticalGrid(...) {
                items(
                    items = bookmarks,
                    key = { bookmark ->
                        bookmark.id
                    }
                ) { curBookmark ->
                    HomeGridItem(
                        ...
                        bookmarkId = curBookmark.id
                        ...
                }
}


@Composable
fun HomeGridItem(
    ...
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .pointerInput(bookmarkId) {
                detectTapGestures(
                    onTap = { onClick() },
                    onLongPress = {
                        onLongClick(globalCoordinates.value)
                    }
                )
            },
    ) { ... }
```